# The number of real values $(x,y)$for which $2^{x+1}+3^y=3^{ y+2}-2^x$ is?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

The number of real values $(x,y)$ for which $$2^{x+1}+3^y=3^{ y+2}-2^x$$ is ?
I went like, $$2^{x+1}+2^x=3^{y+2}-3^y$$
after solving which I got; $(x,y)=(3,1)$
Is there any other process/ solution/ way to solve?

Comment: real or integer? If integer $$2^{x+1}+3^y=3^{y+2}-2^x \\ 3\cdot 2^x = 2^3\cdot 3^y \\ x = 3, \ \ y = 1$$

Comment: real values of x,y to be considered is it the only solution

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math Stackexchange! First of all, could you please explicitly mention the problem and furthermore provide your solution? This is not a site to post homework, but rather to ask assistance in clearing up confusion which arose during a problem!

Comment: Writing this as $2^{x-3}=3^{y-1}$ you can take $\log_3$  of both sides to get $y$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%7Bx%2B1%7D%2B2%5Ex%3D3%5E%7By%2B2%7D-3%5Ey

Comment: Thanks a lot so i think it means there exists only 1 real solution of this question

Comment: What makes  you think that?  Taking $\log_3$ of both sides yields $y=1+(x-3)\log_3(2)$  which makes for infinitely many real solutions (for any $x$ you can use that relation to produce a suitable $y$).

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers A) there are obviously infinitely many solutions, B) the tag [tag:number-theory] is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$ 2^{x+1}+3^y=3^{y+2}-2^x \Leftrightarrow 2^{x+1}+2^x=3^{y+2}-3^y\Leftrightarrow 3\cdot 2^x= 8\cdot 3^y \Leftrightarrow 2^{x-3}=3^{y-1}$, take $\log_3\implies 
\log_32^{x-3}=\log_33^{y-1}\Leftrightarrow (x-3)\log_32=y-1 \implies y=(x-3)\log_32+1,~$in$~\mathbb{R}$.

Over the integers, we have only solution x=3, y=1.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$2^{y}+2^{y+1}=3^{y+2}-3^y\iff 3\times 2^y=8\times3^y\iff 2^{x-3}=3^{y-1}.$$
Now, an investigation on tuples $(x,y)$ (whether real or integer) should be easy.